# Am I truly testing for connection with PostgreSql Server?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am learning about REST API build. I am using FASTAPI and PostgreSQL. I want to start by checking whether it is connected to the server. However, even I disconnect the server using pgadmin4. I get a return response of 200 instead of 503. I am not sure what I am missing at this point. Forgot the original coding too after so many attempts. If you can help, it will be greatly appreciated.

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
    
load_dotenv()

engine = create_engine(url=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'), echo=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def test_db_connection():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        db.execute(text("SELECT 1"))
        db.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Header
from database import test_db_connection

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/health_check", tags=["Public"])
def Health_endpoint(cache_control: str = Header(None)):
     if test_db_connection():
          return Response(status_code=200)
     else:
          return Response(status_code=503)
```

Terminal

```
2024-02-05 22:51:45,954 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
2024-02-05 22:51:45,954 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-02-05 22:51:45,955 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2024-02-05 22:51:45,955 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-02-05 22:51:45,956 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2024-02-05 22:51:45,956 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-02-05 22:51:45,957 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-02-05 22:51:45,957 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT 1
2024-02-05 22:51:45,957 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00010s] {}
2024-02-05 22:51:45,958 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53196 - "GET /health_check HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: Disconnecting the server in pgadmin does not shutdown the server, it just disconnects pgadmin. You will have to shutdown the Postgres Server (depends on installation) explicitly.

Comment: `pgAdmin != Postgres`. `pgAdmin` is just a GUI client used to connect to a Postgres server.